# jQuery Ajax URL encoding, Google maps

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, url

I have a problem. jQuery.ajax method is encoding my URL and I need it "raw". How do I tell it not to encode URLs. I need this for Google maps.

Here is encoded URL used by ajax method:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/jsonaddress=+gererger%C4%87%208,+%C4%8Ca%C4%8Dak,+SRB&sensor=false

and here is how I need it :

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=+8+gerergerć,+Čačak,+SRB&sensor=false

Here is my ajax call :

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url : mapUrl,
            type : 'GET',
            success : function (data, status) {
                if (status === 'success') {
                    if ( typeof data.results[0] !== 'undefined' ) {
                      /* ... */
                    }
                }
            },
            dataType : 'json'
        })
```

My PHP is echoing second URL but ajax is encoding it into first version

Here is how I make mapUrl :

```
var mapUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=<?= $salon->getGoogleMapAddress() ?>&sensor=false';
```

Comment: What is `mapUrl`? There is no way url encoding will turn the second url into the first

Comment: mapUrl is a javascript String. Here is how I make it:

var mapUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=<?= $salon->getGoogleMapAddress() ?>&sensor=false';

Comment: Thanks for helping, guys. It turns out Google understands encoded URLs ;). My URL was just malformed. Sorry if I wasted anybody's time.

Answer (score 0):

try to url encode your string.

```
<?=urlencode($salon->getGoogleMapAddress())?>
```

Comment: That did not help. It only made my PHP string the same as ajax method made it.